# Practical limits of R data frame

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, rcpp

I have been reading about how read.table is not efficient for large data files. Also how R is not suited for large data sets. So I was wondering where I can find what the practical limits are and any performance charts for (1) Reading in data of various sizes (2) working with data of varying sizes.

In effect, I want to know when the performance deteriorates and when I hit a road block. Also any comparison against C++/MATLAB or other languages would be really helpful. finally if there is any special performance comparison for Rcpp and RInside, that would be great!

Comment: the [high performance task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) will almost certainly answer some of these questions.

Comment: Rcpp is a C++ library that wraps the R C API and RInside provides functionality to call R from C++ code.  I.e., they're both constrained by R.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Answer (score 61, accepted):

R *is* suited for large data sets, but you may have to change your way of working somewhat from what the introductory textbooks teach you.  I did a post on [Big Data for R](https://web.archive.org/web/20120501082618/http://www.cybaea.net/Blogs/Data/Big-data-for-R.html) which crunches a 30 GB data set and which you may find useful for inspiration.

The usual sources for information to get started are [High-Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) and the R-SIG HPC mailing list at [R-SIG HPC](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-hpc).

The main limit you have to work around is a historic limit on the length of a vector to 2^31-1 elements which wouldn't be so bad if R did not store matrices as vectors.  (The limit is for compatibility with some BLAS libraries.)

We regularly analyse telco call data records and marketing databases with multi-million customers using R, so would be happy to talk more if you are interested.

Comment: Do you have any statistics on how much data crunching you are doing using R and how much slower is it than say C++ like languages ? Thnx - Egon

Comment: @Egon: My background is such that my first instinct on any data analysis problem is to fire up a text editor and a Fortran compiler.  But these days I find that the limiting factor in the analysis is much more my time figuring out the right approach and translating that into code.  For that, R is so much more productive for me.  For sure I have to think performance carefully when using R, but in truth so must you with compiled code.  I do have some elements that we have compiled, but they are relative few and they were almost all designed and tested in R first.  That's why R is faster.

Answer (score 37):

The physical limits arise from the use of 32-bit indexes on vectors. As a result, vectors up to 2^31 - 1 are allowed. Matrices are vectors with dimensions, so the product of `nrow(mat)` and `ncol(mat)` must be within 2^31 - 1. Data frames and lists are general vectors, so each component can take 2^31 - 1 entries, which for data frames means you can have that many rows *and* columns. For lists you can have 2^31 - 1 components, each of 2^31 - 1 elements. This is drawn from a recent [posting](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/220411/focus=220421) by Duncan Murdoch in reply to a Q on R-Help

Now that all has to fit in RAM with standard R so that might be a more pressing limit, but the [High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) Task View that others have mentioned contains details of packages that can circumvent the in-memory issues.

Comment: Note that the limit of 2^31 - 1 elements only applies to R 2.x.y. In R 3.x.y the limit is higher (see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Long-vectors).

Answer (score 15):

1) The R Import / Export manual should be the first port of call for questions about importing data - there are many options and what will work for your could be very specific.

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html

`read.table` specifically has greatly improved performance if the options provided to it are used, particular `colClasses`, `comment.char`, and `nrows` - this is because this information has to be inferred from the data itself, which can be costly.

2) There is a specific limit for the length (total number of elements) for any vector, matrix, array, column in a data.frame, or list. This is due to a 32-bit index used under the hood, and is true for 32-bit and 64-bit R. The number is 2^31 - 1. This is the maximum number of rows for a data.frame, but it is so large you are far more likely to run out of memory for even single vectors before you start collecting several of them.

See `help(Memory-limits)` and `help(Memory)` for details.

A single vector of that length will take many gigabytes of memory (depends on the type and storage mode of each vector - 17.1 for numeric) so it's unlikely to be a proper limit unless you are really pushing things. If you really need to push things past the available system memory (64-bit is mandatory here) then standard database techniques as discussed in the import/export manual, or memory-mapped file options (like the `ff` package), are worth considering. The CRAN Task View High Performance Computing is a good resource for this end of things.

Finally, if you have stacks of RAM (16Gb or more) and need 64-bit indexing it might come in a future release of R. http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg92035.html

Also, Ross Ihaka discusses some of the historical decisions and future directions for an R like language in papers and talks here: 
http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/?Papers_and_Talks

Answer (score 9):

When reading large csv files `x GB <=> y.1e6 rows` I think `data.table::fread` (as of version 1.8.7) is the quickest alternative you can get it doing `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

You usually gain a factor 5 to 10 (and all `sep`, `row.names` etc are dealt by the function itself). If you have many files and a decent enough computer (several cores), I recommend using the `parallel` package (as part of R.2.14) to load one file per core.

Last time I did this between monothreaded loading with `read.csv` and multithreaded on 4 cores use of `fread` I went from 5 minutes to 20 seconds

Answer (score 8):

I can only answer the one about `read.table`, since I don't have any experience with large data sets. `read.table` performs poorly if you don't provide `colClasses` arguments. Without it, `read.table` defaults to `NA` and tries to guess a class of every column, and that can be slow, especially when you have a lot of columns.