# Trying to edit massive 1.5 GB CSV File

Tags: excel, csv, visual-studio-code, scripting, notepad++

I have been trying to make changes to a csv invoice that my company gets on a monthly basis. However, the File is **1.5 GB** in size and contains over **1.500.000 rows with 36 columns**. While I can open the file in **Microsoft Excel**, trying to edit the data results in a majority of the rows/columns getting deleted without my knowledge. Trying to go in and edit it results in me loosing about 16MB of data. I wrote a PowerShell script to split the file up into two different files, but the problem with that is that one of the CSVs is missing a header and I have to manually add it in. I also have the same issue of some data being deleted despite being under the **1,048,576 rows limit that Excel has**.

I have tried updating the CSV in **Visual Studio Code** and using the **Rainbow CSV extension**, but I'm seeing Visual Studio **crash every time** I try to open the CSV. I have also tried using **Notepad++** and using the **CSV Lite plugin**, but that doesn't have a filter option to make the operation easier. I was wondering if anyone had suggestions for editing a CSV file this big or if they know a way to edit the data in Excel without the risk of data being deleted on accident?

Thank you!

- Editing file in **Excel**, but random data gets deleted without my consent.
- Editing file in **Visual Studio Code**, but it constantly crashes.
- Editing file in **Notepad++**, but the *CSV Lite plugin* isn't as friendly as Excel for filtering data.

Comment: Excel is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: What kind of changes are you trying to make to the CSV file? Is it bulk changes to many/all rows? Or just a couple edits on specific rows? Usually, when people deal with that much data people often develop a program to read only small portions at a time (line by line) rather than loading the entire file at once and then trying to edit it. You may be able to do that in PowerShell since you seem familiar with it.

Comment: Can you import it into an Access table ?

Comment: @Magine Moxios I am trying to make changes to several of the rows. The invoice has a cost center assigned to a subscription and we made a few subscriptions this month that didn't have a cost center associated it. By my estimation, there were about 7 subscriptions missing cost centers and I need to manually add the cost center number to each column that has that subscription. I'll see if there's a easy way to do this in PowerShell, but I'm currently testing the Access Table option to see if it does what excel does.

Comment: @iDevlop Currently importing the csv into the Access Table. The program is struggling a bit, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: vim can handle big files, but I don't know if this big works

Comment: You might be able to use Python somehow to achieve what you need to do. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: R may be able to handle a data set like this. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233769/practical-limits-of-r-data-frame)

Comment: the fact that this is scriptable is a key part of your question that doesn't seem to currently be indicated anywhere in the question post. Please add it. Self-answering is great, but the question should actually contain all information necessary to motivate appropriate answers, which is currently not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MagineMozios had the right idea. It is very easy to write a PowerShell script to edit the CSV data without deleting anything. Here is the PowerShell script I made to edit the data of my 1.5GB CSV File.

Code:

```
# Define the path to the CSV file
$csvPath = "C:\Users\yourfile.csv"  # Replace 'yourfile.csv' with your actual CSV file name

# Load the CSV into a variable
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Iterate through each row in the CSV
foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    # Check if any column contains "SubscriptionName1" and update the "CostCenter" column to "####"
    if ($row.PSObject.Properties.Value -contains "SubscriptionName1") {
        $row."CostCenter" = "####"
    }
    # Check if any column contains "SubscriptionName2" and update the "CostCenter" column to "####"
    elseif ($row.PSObject.Properties.Value -contains "SubscriptionName2") {
        $row."CostCenter" = "####"
    }
    
    elseif ($row.PSObject.Properties.Value -contains "SubscriptionName3") {
        $row."CostCenter" = "####"
    }
}

# Export the updated CSV
$csvData | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInform
```

Thank you to everyone who contributed!

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Comment: For future reference, if suitable, you may want to consider importing the CSV into SQLite and modifying/querying it through queries instead. Last I used it, SQLite had very good built-in support for both importing and exporting CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor will be a good choice for so large CSV file.
https://www.emeditor.com/